# How to detach (change State) List<object> in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to detach a list of objects in EF Core before returning them.

Here is example for one element (this code works):

```cs
public virtual async Task<ResultX<TData>> Add(TData data)
{
    TDbModel model = _mapper.ToModel(data);

    _context.Add(model);
    int changes = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    if(changes <= 0)
    {
        _logger.Error("Failed to add DbModel", new
        {
            DbModelType = model.GetType().Name,
        });
        return ResultX.Fail<TData>(new DatabaseError());
    }

    TData returnData = _mapper.ToData(model);

    _context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Detached;

    return ResultX.Ok(returnData);
}
```

But when I try to do this on this method it fails:

```cs
public virtual async Task<ResultX<List<TData>>> AddRange(List<TData> data)
{
   List<TDbModel> models = data
       .Select(x => _mapper.ToModel(x))
       .ToList();

   _context.AddRange(models);
   int changes = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

   if(changes != data.Count)
   {
        _logger.Error("Failed to add range of DbModels", new
        {
            DbModelType = typeof(TDbModel).Name,
            ExpectedChanges = data.Count,
            Changes = changes,
        });
        return ResultX.Fail<List<TData>>(new DatabaseError());
    }

    List<TData> returnData = models
         .Select(x => _mapper.ToData(x))
         .ToList();
          
    _context.Entry(models).State = EntityState.Detached;
            
    return ResultX.Ok(returnData);
}
```

I get this Exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'List<TDbModel>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.'`

What would be the most efficient way to detach these elements from the list?

My current solution is this:

```cs
foreach(var model in models)
{
    _context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Comment: The two code blocks seems to be the same. A question, why do you want to detach the created object from the context. It doesn't lives outside of the Add method.

Comment: @RobertoFerraris Add and AddRange methods already existed and were implemented, but method did not return inserted elements list so I added it. I did not know that you do not need to detach elements, since existing code was detaching them and I assumed I have to. Thanks

Comment: You didn't include AddRange code in the post so I can't see the code of the method that doesn't work. Anyway from the code before it seems to me that detaching objects from the context is not needed, simply remove it. You detach an object if you return it and doesn't want to have effectes on the context, in your case the object doesn't exists outside the method.

Comment: @RobertoFerraris I edited my post with code (didn't even see that I copied the same thing). Thanks for your help though. I will remove the detaching process.

Comment: @MartinFerenec first of all, this `Add` is a critical bug, not just major, which breaks EF Core's Unit-of-Work semantics. A DbContext instance is a UoW, detecting all changes in the objects it tracks. `SaveChanges` is **only** called at the end, to persist all pending changes in a single transaction. Before that there's not even an open connection. Calling `_context.SaveChangesAsync();` right after tracking a single new object with `Add` fatally breaks this. The only way to recover is to use keep a long lived connection and explicit database transactions. Don't do that

Comment: Detaching `model` won't fix the real bug. As for the exception you posted, where is it raised? It complains about `List<object>`, not entities. Somehow, somewhere, something is returning a `List<object>` instead of `List<TData>`, unless `TData` is an `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error depends on the fact that `AddRange` of _context add the single objects of the `models` list, not the list itself. So the `models` object is never added to the dbcontext, and as a result `_context.Entry(models)` couldn't find it.

If you want detach the objects in the list you must do it individually, as you already found by yourself.

I suggest to investigate the code that uses the Add and AddRange methods. @PanagiotisKanavos it's right, the db context must be used as a unit of work, if you add items and then detach them, there must be a valid reason (that I couldn't imagine) to do it.